# My Table alignment became right after it sent (HTML Email for newsletter)

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, html-email

I got a problem with my table alignment. (HTML Newsletter email)
Everything looks normal when I open it in Dreamweaver, open it on my browser and open it or attach it as text in my outlook mail. (before I send it)
But when I send it by attaching it into the email as text, the recipient will see that the alignment for the table became right. (I actually put everything in it with left alignment with text-align) I am new to this HTML thing.

Here is my email code in the code snippet:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <tr>
    <td valign="center" align="center" class="p30-15" style="padding: 20px 0px 30px 0px;">
      <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-shell">
      <tr>
         <td class="text-center pt40" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan Medium'; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; text-align:left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><strong>Deployment Detail :</strong></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td" style="width:650px; min-width:650px; font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" dir="rtl" style="direction: rtl;">
              <tr>
                <th class="column-top"  dir="ltr" width="100%" align="left" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; text-align: left; vertical-align:top;">
                  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; align-content: center; align-self: center; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Maintenance and Deployment</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Saturday, 25th December 2021 01:00 AM UTC (UK Time)</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Friday, 31st December 2021 13:00 PM UTC (UK Time)</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Release 2.62.00</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Medium</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">All Users</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:11px; line-height:31px; text-align:left; vertical-align: top; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">1.) System reset feature (every 90 days)<br />
                        2.) Data Renewal from 2013 to 2019 for inactive data<br />
                        3.) monthly maintenance<br />
                        <strong>The Apps will not be accessible</strong> during the mentioned date &amp; time. Kindly ensure you logged out from system to avoid data loss.</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;" ><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Helpdesk@classy.com</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;" ><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">#12345678</p></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </th>
                <!--<th class="column-empty" dir="ltr" width="60" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; vertical-align:top;"></th>-->
                <th class="column" dir="ltr" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal;">
                  <table align="left" width="200" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Event Type</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#0000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Start Date & Time</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">End Date & Time</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Release Version</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Impact</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#0000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Affected Users</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" height="155" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Remarks</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#0000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Contact</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#0000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Reference Number</p></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the email (the table part) when the user received it:
[image]

I really appreciate it if you guys can help me on it or have any solution for my problem.
Thank you.

Best Regards,
MST

Comment: what is the property of this class `text pb20`

Comment: remove this `dir="ltr"`

Comment: I'm not too sure why it's doing what it's doing; but I am slightly confused why that left column is a seperate table from the right?

Comment: Let me try to remove the dir suggested by Lalji

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan yeah, I actually don't really know either why the table separate haha

Comment: It's because you've defined it as seperate in the HTML - I was just confused why you'd done it that way

Comment: Wow Insane help you guys, the problem solved!
@LaljiTadhani your suggestion is right after deleting the ltr all is good now.
Thank you for you too Andrew maybe you can tell me more about the separation thingy in my table so I can make it better.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. This HTML structure will fix your issue.**

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <tr>
    <td valign="center" align="center" class="p30-15" style="padding: 20px 0px 30px 0px;">
      <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="mobile-shell">
      <tr>
         <td class="text-center pt40" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan Medium'; font-size:20px; line-height:30px; text-align:left; vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;"><strong>Deployment Detail :</strong></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="td" style="width:650px; min-width:650px; font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal;">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <th class="column" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal;">
                  <table align="left" width="200" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Event Type</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#0000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Start Date & Time</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:5px; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">End Date & Time</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Release Version</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Impact</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#0000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Affected Users</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" height="155" style="color:#000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Remarks</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#0000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Contact</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#0000000; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:14px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Reference Number</p></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </th>
                <th class="column-top" width="100%" align="left" style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; padding:0; margin:0; font-weight:normal; text-align: left; vertical-align:top;">
                  <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; align-content: center; align-self: center; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Maintenance and Deployment</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Saturday, 25th December 2021 01:00 AM UTC (UK Time)</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:bold; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Friday, 31st December 2021 13:00 PM UTC (UK Time)</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Release 2.62.00</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Medium</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">All Users</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:11px; line-height:31px; text-align:left; vertical-align: top; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">1.) System reset feature (every 90 days)<br />
                        2.) Data Renewal from 2013 to 2019 for inactive data<br />
                        3.) monthly maintenance<br />
                        <strong>The Apps will not be accessible</strong> during the mentioned date &amp; time. Kindly ensure you logged out from system to avoid data loss.</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;" ><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">Helpdesk@classy.com</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text pb20" style="color:#777777; font-family:'Spartan SemiBold'; font-size:12px; line-height:32px; text-align:left; font-weight:normal; padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;" ><p style="text-align: left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">#12345678</p></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```